How to remove the line breaks that Visual Studio Code includes when saving the code
How to remove the line breaks that's added in the formatting when saving the code in VSCode
For example:
If I have an expression with multiple validations:
if True == True or False == True or False == False:

It is being formatted as:
if (True == True
or False == True
or False == False)

This complicates readability. How can I reformat it to look like the first example?

Turn off VSCode's automatic reformatting. This is not something that Python does.

but if i do it, the code will be reformatted?

No, that's the whole point. I don't use VSCode, so I can't tell you precisely what option to change. But there should be a way to turn off things like this.

There may also be a list of specific formatting options, and you can just disable this one.

@Barmar VS Code buries this option pretty deeply, it may be tough to find.  You probably need to go to a section specific to Python.

@MarkRansom, OP, et al: there's a checkbox for "Format on Save" in the Settings. It's not language specific, by the look of it. You can find it by typing that right into the "Search settings" field once you open Settings.

Related: How do I turn off text formatting on save in visual studio code?  Although, the answers are all over the place; most of them seem to say "Save without formatting always instead of changing your settings."

You can use the shortcut Ctrl+, to open the settings. Input format on save and deselect the Editor:Format On Save option. This disables the use of code formatting when saving documents globally. This preserves the format of the code you wrote it.

First check to see which formatter VSCode is using to format your code. In most cases (I tried Black and Ruff), you can disable the formatting of a specific piece of code by wrapping it inside the below block:
# fmt: off
lst = [1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6,
       7, 8 ,9]
# fmt: on

Without that comment, it would put them in single line.
I guess most formatters will respect that comment.

autopep8 also respects that comment
